# what is the javascript equivalent of .NET's DateTime.Date property?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to take an arbitrary javascript date object and strip out the time portion.  In .NET you would use the DateTime object's **[Date property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

What is the javascript equivalent?  I've seen people doing this:

```
var now = new Date();
var justDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
```

Is this the preferred way?  Should I throw this code in a utils module or is there a more simple way of doing this?

I'm using **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** and jquery- any solution using either library is certainly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

All JavaScript dates have time information.  This will just set the time portion to 00:00.000  local time.  This can be useful when you want to compare dates.

Answer (score 2):

With moment.js you could use `moment(0,"HH").toDate()`